# Symfony 2.7 form builder with new field from another entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So I start off with my database layout, I have a `User` table which has an `accounts_id` link to another table `Accounts`.

Inside `Accounts` I have `companyname`. Now I have built a AbstractType for my user sign up. I want this form to include a field for `companyname`. But what I have tried is not working, so where is what I have done so far,

```
use XBundle\Form\AccountType;

class UserType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('firstname', 'text',['label'=>'Firstname'])
            ->add('surname', 'text',['label'=>'Surname'])

            //->add('companyname','text', ['data_class' => 'XBundle\Entity\Accounts'])

            ->add('companyname', new AccountType()) <- current attempt

            ->add('email', 'email',['label'=>'Email'])
            ->add('password', 'password',['label'=>'Password']);

            //->add('confirm', 'password', ['mapped' => false,'label'=>'Re-type password'])
            //->add('homepage', 'text',['label'=>'Homepage'])

            //->add('save', 'submit', ['label'=>'Register']);
  }

  public function getName() {
      return 'registration';
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'XBundle\Entity\Users',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ]);
  }
}
```

And for my `AccountType` I have the following,

```
class AccountType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('companyname','text', ['label'=>'Company']);       
  }

  public function getName() {
    return 'account';
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'XBundle\Entity\Accounts',
    ]);
  }
}
```

When I build a `createForm & createView` for my twig (which renders without any problems without the `companyname / AccountType`). I get the following error,

```
Neither the property "companyname" 
nor one of the methods "getCompanyname()", 
"companyname()", "isCompanyname()", "hasCompanyname()", 
"__get()" exist and have public access in class "XBundle\Entity\Users"
```

Now I know that `companyname` is in my `Accounts Entity`. I have also done a test to make sure my `AccountType` works, by building a new form with that type, which renders the `Company Name` field without any problems.

But I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or even if this is the right way about going about adding another entities field on my user sign up form, please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is expected.

`AccountType` is a form to edit `Account` entity details. By adding `companyname` to the builder you explicily say that setters and getters exists for that property. An this part is correct.

`UserType` is a form to edit `User` entity details, NOT `Account` details. If you add an `AccountType` property named `companyname`,the form component expect you to provide these methods:

```
public function getCompanyname() {/*...*/}
public function setCompanyname(Account $account) {/*...*/}
```

Which is not what you are expecting, and exactly what the error is saying.

You need to provide accessor for the `Account` to your user entity, and then define how the form should handle it.

### Option 1: you want to select an existing account

Add this to the `UserType` builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    // options are guessed anyway, you choose if set it explicitly or not
    $builder->add('account'/*, 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'XBundle:Account'
    )*/);
}
```

And the following to your `User` entity:

```
class User {
    private $account;

    public function getAccount() {
        return $this->account;
    }

    public function setAccount(Account $account /* = null, if optional */) {
        $this->account = $account;
    }
}
```

### Option 2: you want one-to-one association and an editable account

Add this to the `UserType` builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('account', new AccountType());
}
```

And the following to your `User` entity:

```
class User {
    private $account;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->account = new Account();
    }

    public function getAccount() {
        return $this->account;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I have done that. But this only gives me an empty pull down list? I need it to be a text input to save the company name field within the Accounts Entity. - sorry I must be doing something wrong.... very new to Symfony!

Comment: You get an empty list, since the `entity` type is about selecting existing entity from DB. You want to edit an entity, you need to use the `AccountType` and ensure the the `Account` property is always initialized in User class. Note that by doing this you set a strong one-to-one association between user and account.

Comment: thanks, but I am not understanding this - and the docs on the site don't help me very much. I don't want a one-to-one. Many users will have one account, so (unless I am wrong) I want a ManytoOne relationship. I come from using CakePHP, and this is quite easy to do with Cake. But I think this could be a little bit beyond me..... thanks for your help

Comment: I have set it up with your option 2 - which seems to work. If I need to ask this in a new question, I will. But how can I save that data all in one hit. If I 'persist' the User with the form data, it tries to add NULL to the Account_id field within the user, so not saving the account/company names field...

Comment: Also in Symfony is easy when you know how to do it :) If you want to either save a new entity or choose an existing one, become more complex. You can (for example) set 2 fields: the default one to select the type (option 1) and an unmapped  one to create a new Account. Then the controller or a form listener should choose which of the two is more important. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html for example. For the problem of the "null" value, you need to set cascade-persist on the doctrine association definition.

Comment: cascade is set to all in my doctrine mapping - not sure whats going on right now.... I am not a big fan of the docs, and there seems to be little 'more' than beginner training vids. If you know of anything, cost not an option, please point me to it, thanks.

Comment: I cannot help with fine debug, since I cannot access to the full code. Just make sure that "account" is mapped in doctrine, the php "User::account" property is set and that the user association to account is cascade persist. It should work. For the form, interface.. well I know is hard to use in complex case, but you need to get used to it. The link above and the other resources are a good starting point. Maybe you could search/ask other specific question for that

Comment: I think i had something wrong somewhere, it now seems to be pointing to other records that are not set to null in my Accounts - set them to null (temp test) and it did save the data.... not sure if I am going or coming with Doctrine... but many many thanks for your help